# Al tratar de mostrar un atributo de un objeto en una vista JSP java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "idUsuario"

Tags: jsp, spring, spring-mvc, foreach, jstl

tengo un problema, cuando intento mostrar el atributo de un elemento de una lista de objetos EN MI JSP que he añadido al model en el controlador, me da un error de NumberFormatException. No le veo ningún sentido. He buscado mil soluciones y no encentro nada que me sea de ayuda o que me solucione el problema.

En el POJO tengo todos los métodos getters y setters de todos los atributos. He revisado otros proyectos y todo está puesto de la misma forma, no sé qué podría estar fallando. En otro sitio leí que tal vez en vez de como objetos, el modelo lo está guardando como un String y no reconoce la propiedad, pero si es ese caso no lo veo claro ni tampoco la solución.

Me vendría bien un poco de ayuda. Gracias.

La **traza** es la siguiente:

```html
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para servlet [jsp] lanzó una excepción
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "idUsuario"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:144)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:61)
 at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
 at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
 at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:944)
 at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.web.login_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(login_jsp.java:213)
 at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.web.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:135)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

ago 14, 2019 11:57:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [mvc-dispatcher] en el contexto con ruta [/GestionAlicia] lanzó la excepción [java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "idUsuario"] con causa raíz
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "idUsuario"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:144)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:61)
 at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
 at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
 at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:944)
 at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.web.login_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(login_jsp.java:213)
 at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.web.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:135)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

En mi **controlador**, añado la lista (que se obtiene correctamente de base de datos) de la siguiente forma:

```html
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String list(Model model) {
     List<Usuario> usuarios = userFacade.findAll();
     model.addAttribute("usuarios", usuarios);
     return "web/login";
   }
```

Y en el **JSP**, que es donde mete el petardazo, lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
 <head>
 <title>Hola</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 
    <h1>Lista de usuarios</h1>
    <ul>
 
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${usuarios}">
            <li>Codigo: ${user.idUsuario} </li>
        </c:forEach>
 </ul> 
      
    
</body>
</html>
```

**EL POJO**

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario {
 @Id
 @Column(name="id_usuario")
 private Integer idUsuario;
 
 @Column(name="codigo_usuario")
 private String codigoUsuario;
 
 @Column(name="password")
 private String password;

 public Integer getIdUsuario() {
  return idUsuario;
 }

 public void setIdUsuario(Integer idUsuario) {
  this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
 }

 public String getCodigoUsuario() {
  return codigoUsuario;
 }

 public void setCodigoUsuario(String codigoUsuario) {
  this.codigoUsuario = codigoUsuario;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
  return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result + ((codigoUsuario == null) ? 0 : codigoUsuario.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((idUsuario == null) ? 0 : idUsuario.hashCode());
  return result;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj)
   return true;
  if (obj == null)
   return false;
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
   return false;
  Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
  if (codigoUsuario == null) {
   if (other.codigoUsuario != null)
    return false;
  } else if (!codigoUsuario.equals(other.codigoUsuario))
   return false;
  if (idUsuario == null) {
   if (other.idUsuario != null)
    return false;
  } else if (!idUsuario.equals(other.idUsuario))
   return false;
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "usuario [idUsuario=" + idUsuario + ", codigoUsuario=" + codigoUsuario + "]";
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HE encontardo la solución, quizás le sirva a alguien que tenga el mismo problema. El problema estaba en el DAO. Me di cuenta de que no me estaba trayendo una lista de Usuarios, sino una lista de Objectos, por lo cual no encontraba la propiedad idUsuario (supongo).

Mi dao antes de ser corregido:

```html
public List<Usuario> findAll() {
  Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  List<Usuario> lista = (List<Usuario>)session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM usuario").list();
  return lista;
 }
```

Y mi dao correcto:

```html
public List<Usuario> findAll() {
  Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  List<Usuario> lista = (List<Usuario>)session.createQuery("FROM Usuario").list();
  return lista;
 }
```

Por algún motivo, el SQL no lo estaba haciendo yo bien porque no enlazaba bien con el objeto "Usuario", así que de momento he optado por el HQL y va tirando.

Comment: Si esto resolvió tu pregunta, marca tu respuesta como la respuesta aceptada.

Comment: Hola, Juan, soy nueva y no sabía que había que marcarlas, gracias. Me dice que debo esperar 20 horas, lo haré en cuanto hayan pasado.